# i need a help to decide which country code ISO should i use for my app

Tags: android

what this code returns in your countries.

```
TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String SIMCountryISO=tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

is it return two charater or three char. please reply with your countries and result

Answer (score 0):

It will return an [alpha-2 code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2).

I am a bit suprised that [the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkCountryIso%28%29) isnt more specific about which type of ISO country code but...

> Returns the ISO country code equivalent of the current registered
>   operator's MCC (Mobile Country Code).

**Please also note**:

- MCC = [Mobile Country Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code) and are 3 digits.
- MNC = [Mobile Network Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code) and can be 2 or 3 digits.  The MCC + MNC combination represent a specific carrier.
- Country ISO (or country code iso) = Normally [ISO_3166-1_alpha-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) and are 2 capital letters.  They represent a country (not a language).

Since countries never share MCC codes, you can infer the country from just the MCC code.  That is exactly what this method does and will return the 2 character ISO code for the country.

Language ISO codes are completely different and represent a specific language.  The combination of Language ISO code + Country ISO code is called a locale.  The language iso code is normally lower case.

E.g. en_US

Comment: in my country returns the two digit code may be in other countries returns the three digit code

Comment: Then it would be inconsistent which would make the function useless.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ - I deleted my post. You are right. I've used this before (and correctly!), but it's been awhile. I appreciate your persistence in getting it straight!

Comment: @phil what should i do to get user country name from user

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find country codes from various resources online.  You wouldn't have to go ask the community to do test for you; and doing so is not what StackOverflow is intended for.

Try using a list such as [this](http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html) one to accommodate your needs.